# Cannot run grunt task after installing angularfullstack

Tags: angularjs, sass, yeoman, angular-fullstack

I got the error below, reinstalled yeoman and angular-fullstack.  The message disappeared last night and I was able to connect to my localhost, but came back again when I was trying to run **grunt serve**    (yes I tried installing sass)

> total 698ms/Users/nho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'sass' (>= 0) among 29 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
>       Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/nho/.gem/ruby/2.2.0:/Users/nho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0', execute`gem env`for more information
>           from /Users/nho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:324:in`to_spec'
>           from /Users/nho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:64:in `gem'
>           from /Users/nho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/sass:22:in`'
>           from /Users/nho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
>           from /Users/nho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
Could not find 'sass'
```

Please try to install it on your system.

http://sass-lang.com/install

Comment: tried that before coming on here.  tried that again and that didn't work